# Why int variable id's in python 2.7 are equal only until 256?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Why int variable `id's` in python 2.7 are equal only until 256 ?

For example:

```
>>> y = 256
>>> m = 256
>>> m is y
True
>>> y = 257
>>> m = 257
>>> id(m)
16282096
>>> id(y)
16281952
>>> m is y
False
```

Comment: Implementation detail; small integers are interned (made singletons) as a tradeoff between performance and memory footprint.

Comment: The range is `-5 to 256` including (-5 and 256). This is done for performance optimization.

Comment: http://www.laurentluce.com/posts/python-integer-objects-implementation/

Comment: PyObject* PyInt_FromLong(long ival)
Return value: New reference.
Create a new integer object with a value of ival.

The current implementation keeps an array of integer objects for all integers between -5 and 256, when you create an int in that range you actually just get back a reference to the existing object. So it should be possible to change the value of 1. I suspect the behaviour of Python in this case is undefined. :-)

Comment: It's really irrelevant. You shouldn't use `id` in the first place.